Why is there a cap on the maximum number of questions per day for non newbie users?
Right now, a user cannot ask more than 6 questions per 24 hours. While this is an effective method to prevent spam, can we increase this for users with higher reputation (say, those with more than 50 reputation points)?
Since 24.04 just became on topic on this site, I want to ask (and answers) many questions about problems I faced and their workarounds, and right now I am unable to ask all of them.

An interesting question, but it bumps into a limit that is not set by Ask Ubuntu itself ..

If you attempted to produce content at such a high rate, perhaps the quality could —inadvertently— suffer?

I think 6 questions per day is more than enough for anybody - new or experienced user alike. If you as a general user have more than 6 different problems in one day, then I'd say you have at least another problem of some sort (maybe you're just trying to do too many things at once).
I can understand that you want to ask and self-answer a bunch of questions. This is a noble cause indeed, but as Muru said, it's OK to prioritise, and eventually you'll get through it.

If you as a general user have more than 6 different problems in one day, then I'd say you have at least another problem of some sort -- I have been using 24.04 for more than a month. It is ubuntu which has the bug, not my use case https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/2046844 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/safeeyes/+bug/2056233

@ArchismanPanigrahi this wasn't exactly directed at you, since I acknowledge that the release of a new OS can pose challenges like this.

In the general case, this is to prevent a user from posting a bunch of questions about some topic without doing enough research on it. You can see this happen even with experienced users. I know of a couple of high rep users who often did/still do this, one with 10k+ rep, one 1k+ - they'd grab some new topic and then we'd see a bunch of usually trivial questions on it. And not just on AU, but spreading their posts over U&L and SO as well. Without question limits, I have no doubt we'd see dozens of low-quality posts spammed all over the network from high-rep users.
I don't think new Ubuntu releases merit an exception for this. If the problems that you have answers for are truly that important, other users will post questions about them sooner or later. Just answer then. Or, find questions about the same problem which differ only in the Ubuntu version, and answer there. It's a common practice here to generalise questions beyond a specific release if possible, so that's fine. (This IMO is the best option for software-installation questions.)
In the meantime, prioritise. Decide which of the problems you don't have answers to are most important and post those. It's just a new Ubuntu release that's not being forced on anyone. There's no real need to raise the limits for that.
